# Cyclonedx (gradle) - Unable to resolve POM

Tags: java, gradle, sbom, cyclonedx

My project is completely Gradle written on Java (structure is that my root project has multiple sub projects and a few sub projects depend on few other sub projects).

I applied the `cyclonedxBom` plugin to all the sub projects (included this plugin in the `build.gradle` of each sub project) like indicated below.

```
plugin {
  id 'org.cyclonedx.bom' version "1.8.2"
}
```

When I am executing the command `./gradlew cyclonedxBom`, I see that the sbom files are generated (both xml and json) for all the sub projects.

However, I see a few errors on the console like below that mentions multiple sub projects.

```
Unable to resolve POM for com.myproject.sub-project-1:24.1.0-SNAPSHOT
 
Could not resolve all files for configuration ':sub-project2:detachedConfiguration1'
```

After searching for a few hints on the web, I came across this git issue https://github.com/CycloneDX/cyclonedx-gradle-plugin/issues/321 which sounds similar to mine. I tried to use the plugin version `1.8.2` as mentioned in the git issue (I was using `1.8.1` earlier), but I still see these errors.

1. I am curious to know why and how the gradle plugin is looking for a pom file for a completely gradle project.
2. Is there any impact to the sbom generation (whether all the dependencies are included properly in the output file or not)?

P.S: The plugin version `1.6.1` doesn't seem to be throwing any error, but the version `1.8.2` does.

Any pointers here are appreciated.